# boost asio and coroutine2 example

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-coroutine, boost-coroutine2

While reading the documentation of `coroutine2` I found a nice [snippet](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/coroutine2/doc/html/coroutine2/motivation.html#ftn.coroutine2.motivation.f0) of code that shows how to use it with `asio`

For reference here's the code from the documentation:

```
void session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service){
    // construct TCP-socket from io_service
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);

    try{
        for(;;){
            // local data-buffer
            char data[max_length];

            boost::system::error_code ec;

            // read asynchronous data from socket
            // execution context will be suspended until
            // some bytes are read from socket
            std::size_t length=socket.async_read_some(
                    boost::asio::buffer(data),
                    boost::asio::yield[ec]);
            if (ec==boost::asio::error::eof)
                break; //connection closed cleanly by peer
            else if(ec)
                throw boost::system::system_error(ec); //some other error

            // write some bytes asynchronously
            boost::asio::async_write(
                    socket,
                    boost::asio::buffer(data,length),
                    boost::asio::yield[ec]);
            if (ec==boost::asio::error::eof)
                break; //connection closed cleanly by peer
            else if(ec)
                throw boost::system::system_error(ec); //some other error
        }
    } catch(std::exception const& e){
        std::cerr<<"Exception: "<<e.what()<<"\n";
    }
}
```

However I can't find a working example on the asio documentation, and trying to compile this snippet on coliru gives me compiler errors related to `yield`

Are you aware of a minimal client/server implementation that uses `coroutine2` as showed in the example above?

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK boost.asio supports only boost.coroutine, not boost.coroutine2

Comment: the example in the coroutine2 documentation is misleading then. That is too bad, it would be great to have it supported.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14285746)

Comment: @kiamlaluno to me, it's answering this question

Comment: @Danh It is quite short to be an answer. A link to the documentation, and a quote of the part saying what the answer says would be added value.

Comment: @kiamlaluno It doesn't support, it means that there are no documentation for it

Comment: @Danh They document if a library supports another library, or the requirements a library has.

Comment: "Since version 1.54.0, Boost.Asio supports coroutines. While you could use Boost.Coroutine directly, explicit support of coroutines in Boost.Asio makes it easier to use them." That is taken from https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.asio-coroutines.

Comment: @kiamlaluno quite ironic that you chose to quote something that is **not** Boost documentation, as well as it doesn't document that Coroutine2 is not supported :)

Comment: @sehe I find something else to be ironic, like saying that if A is not supported by B, then no documentation will say that.

Answer (score 4):

An example Boost.Asio-based server using coroutines is given [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/spawn/echo_server.cpp).

The example shown in the Boost.Coroutine documentation is missing the part where `boost::asio::spawn` is used to create a `yield_context` that can be passed as a asynchronous handler.

By following the `#include` chain within `<boost/asio/spawn.hpp>`, it seems to include Boost.Coroutine v1 only.